# VPN clients not reaching Internet

Tags: linux, debian, openvpn, vpn, vps

Recently, during VPN server configuration the one thing that I've faced is - I don't have internet access connecting through my VPN server. Actually I use the VPS(Debian 8 ), where I've installed a VPN. The client connects normally I've used the trace route command to detect where traffic stops, and obviously it stops at my VPN server. I really don't know how to deal with it. Anyone help me please:) Here's my Server config and Client config. And yes my client side is Windows 7 and 10.

Server config.

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

Client config. Note: Server's IP is hidden.

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 107.155.1x4.1x2 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca "C:\\OVPN\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\OVPN\\client1.crt"
key "C:\\OVPN\\client1.key"
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

From client side I tried to test Google's DNS server 8.8.8.8 - still it doesn't work. I think the problem lies with some of the interfaces on the server side which break outs to internet. So anyone who suggests something, just help me with useful advice.

**"Add the output of the following commands please: sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward, iptables-save, ip route show. On the client maybe: route print. – rda "**

1) The outuput for `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` is

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

2) The output for `ip route show` is

```
10.8.0.2 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.02 dev tun0
default dev venet0 scope link
```

3) And Outuput for `iptables-save` is

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [241673:29858781]
:INPUT ACCEPT [232866:29385621]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [8803:472884]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [250884:4018010]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [259688:40653794]
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [232866:29385621]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [8804:472884]
:OUTUPUT ACCEPT [250884:40180910]
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [20668:1262348]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [14826:1006759]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10970:791257]
COMMIT
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [241673:29858781]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [250884:40180910]
COMMIT
```

**June 11**

I believe the problem lies in routing tables, I've run the command - `netstat -nr` , and surprisingly I've found that in my routing table I've strange IP addresess which are assigned only for VPN using.**

Here, take a look:

Kernel IP routing table(Note: the routing table parameters go as following in column(!), Ex: the routing table's IP take all first parameters from first column. And last three parameters `MSS Window irtt` are the same for each value of routing table.

```
Destination face 10.8.0.2 un0 10.8.0.0 un0 0.0.0.0 enet0 

Gateway face 0.0.0.0 un0 10.8.0.2 un0 0.0.0.0 enet0 

Genmask face 255.255.255.255 un0 255.255.255.0 un0 0.0.0.0 enet0 

Flags face UH un0 UG un0 U enet0 

MSS Window irtt face 0 0 0 un0 0 0 0 un0 0 0 0 enet0
```

**June 15**

Hey buddy! Thanks for your reply again!

the output for `ip route show` is:

```
10.8.0.2 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.0/24 via 
10.8.0.2 dev tun0 default dev venet0 scope link
```

the output for following command on VPS `ip route get 8.8.8.8` is(Note: IP address is hidden):

```
8.8.8.8 dev venet0 src 107.155.1x4.1x2 
    cache mtu 1500 advmss 1460 hoplimit 64
```

On the client side - I used this command `route print` - I got hell of a big page of IP addresses, but I don't know what is important here to solve this this problem...

What are the next steps?

Big thanks to you again for your help, really

**Update 15 June**

So here's the output for command `route print` on windows client:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active routes:
Network address        Subnet mask        Gateway          Interface   Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.88.1   192.168.88.208     20
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     192.168.50.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.50.1    276
     192.168.50.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.50.1    276
   192.168.50.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.50.1    276
     192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
   192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
     192.168.88.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.88.208    276
   192.168.88.208  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.88.208    276
   192.168.88.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.88.208    276
    192.168.100.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.100.1    276
    192.168.100.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.100.1    276
  192.168.100.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.100.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.88.208    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.100.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.50.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.88.208    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.100.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.50.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
===========================================================================
Permanent routes:
```

**Update June 17**

Hey buddy, I've tried using those commands which enable NAT on server, unfortunatelly again it doesn't work. The output for `ip route show` is the same like it was before:

```
10.8.0.2 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0
default dev venet0 scope link
```

Those commands that you gave me,  were running smoothly, but didn't bring any results. So, new IP route just doesn't appear in output! I tried adding the same route different ways, even changed the mask from /16 to /24, still nothing.

The only one **important** thing that made me feel strange is - I've ran my OVPN Gui at client side, and I know that internet doesn't work, and what I see, from the start my Facebook page starts to load, but other ones like google.com or linkedin.com - or any other website - they just don't open...

Some minor things about my VPS provider, at FAQ page they tell the following things:

```
**22
    Do you support TUN/TAP? IPSEC?

    Yes, TUN/TAP and IPSEC are enabled on all VPS by default.**


**2
What kind of virtualization is offered/used?

We utilize OpenVZ on our infrastructure. If you require KVM virtualization we recommend SpeedyKVM.**
```

What this problem may be And how we can overcome this?

Again big thanks to you!

Comment: I believe, that Yes. I used the OpenVPN guide from digital ocean ( https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-debian-8 ) "sorry if i can't put here external links". So by this guide I've configured the IP masquerading, and some policies to allow ipv4 traffic to go through the VPN server. By default, when I connect to VPN from any computer, VPN assigns the same IP address to each client 10.0.8.6 ( something like this) but anyway, I have connection only between client-VPN. What Can I do here?

Comment: I believe that no, I don't know any VPS firewall rules...How Can I find them and change if so?

Comment: It is dependent on your VPS provider - Amazon as a web interface for instance. Add your VPS provider to the post, please.

Comment: I use the www.wable.com

Comment: I can send you the logs from VPS, let's ping something what's important, so I will know about what to talk to them

Comment: How I can connect to port 443(tcp) or 1194(udp) of any site? I know only how to ping :d Yeah I can ping google's DNS 8.8.8.8 it works fine

Comment: telnet gmail.com 443

Comment: Still it doesn't work. The output for - telnet gmail.com 443 is " Connection closed by foreign host". And output for - telnet gmail.com 1194 is " Unable to connect to remote host. Connection timed out" What we gonna do next?

Comment: It does not seem firewall at least. Maybe someone can help you with openvpn, as I more familiar with ipsec vpns.

Comment: :( It's the 8th forum where I've posted the same thread(( I don't know where to post it again so people can find it and help me, any suggestions?

Comment: Add the output of the following commands please: `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`, `iptables-save`, `ip route show`. On the client maybe: `route print`.

Comment: 1) The outuput for "sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward" is going to be "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1". 2) The output for "ip route show" is - 
10.8.0.2 dev tun0 proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.1
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.02 dev tun0
default dev venet0 scope link

Comment: 3) And Outuput for "iptables-save" is:
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sun Jun 12 03:01:07 2016
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [241673:29858781]
:INPUT ACCEPT [232866:29385621]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [8803:472884]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [250884:4018010]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [259688:40653794]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jun 12 03:01:07 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v.1.4.21 on Sun Jun 12 03:01:07 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [232866:29385621]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [8804:472884]
:OUTUPUT ACCEPT [250884:40180910]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jun 12 03:01:07 2016

Comment: *nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [20668:1262348]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [14826:1006759]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10970:791257]
COMMIT
# completed on Sun Jun 12 03:01:07 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v.1.4.21 on Sun Jun 12 03:01:07 2016
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [241673:29858781]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [250884:40180910]
COMMIT
# completed on Sun Jun 12 03:01:07 2016

Comment: I believe the problem lies in routing tables, I've run the command - netstat -nr , and surprisingly I've found that in my routing table I've strange IP addresess which are assigned only for VPN using. Here, take a look:
Kernel IP routing table

Destination face 10.8.0.2 un0 10.8.0.0 un0 0.0.0.0 enet0
Gateway face 0.0.0.0 un0 10.8.0.2 un0 0.0.0.0 enet0
Genmask face 255.255.255.255 un0 255.255.255.0 un0 0.0.0.0 enet0
Flags face UH un0 UG un0 U enet0
MSS Window irtt face 0 0 0 un0 0 0 0 un0 0 0 0 enet0

Comment: That's it buddy, check this out

Comment: The routes on the client for the vpn network `10.8.0.0/24` are missing. Either your vpn client was not connected or there is some problem with the vpn configuration. Note: the vpn client has to run with administrative permissions in order to install the routes.

Comment: Maybe check out this answer for more details: http://superuser.com/a/505220/299628 And try the SNAT variant from my answer when your client routing is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable NAT on the server.

SNAT for static IP address:

```bsh
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/16 -o <if> -j SNAT --to <ip>
```

Or if you have a dynamically assigned IP address use `MASQUERADE` (slower):

```bsh
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/16 -o <if> -j MASQUERADE
```

while

- **`<if>`** is the name of the external interface (i.e. `venet0`)
- **`<ip>`** is the IP address of the external interface

Comment: Hey buddy, I tried to run this command and unfortunately I still can't break out to the internet:( What we gonna do next?

Comment: How we can do that?

Comment: @woozyman In your question you already posted the firewall configuration using `iptables-save` or `iptables- vnL`, which does not restrict anything and should not make problems. Maybe check if the routing table on your server is correct using `ip route show`. I noticed the missing `via <gateway_ip>` in the `default` line, which could indicate that the interface has a direct connection via cable or this might be a special circumstance for virtual hosts. The interface name `venet0` could indicate that OpenVZ is used for virtualization. But I do not have any experiance with this.

Comment: @woozyman on your windows client's you can check the routing using cmd `route print`. Maybe check on the server if the routing is working using `ip route get 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Check out please my main comment box(15 June) the last message - I've left there the outputs for those commands, check this out please!:)

Comment: @woozyman the section after `IPv4 Route Table` with all the IPv4 addresses is the important part. Some routes with `10.8.0.0` should be presend. And please add these tables and the ones from your last comment to your question with proper formatting (code block) otherwise its very hard to read.

Comment: Which is command to get ipv4 route table? Because the outpot from those commands that you gave me isn't enough I see

Comment: @woozyman `route print` on windows

Comment: Here we go buddy, check out "Update June 15". Big thanks!

Comment: hey buddy check please new update " Update June 17". thanks!

Comment: Dear rda, big thanks to you... After your last message I have added the routing and I got the internet fully working through my VPN. So it's solved:) Wish you the best my friend!

Comment: hey @woozyman buddy. Great to hear I've helped and that it works. It would be interesting for me to know what exactly you did to solve it. And by the way: you should not put `<solved>` in the title. Rather accept the answer that solved the problem or write your own answer explaining what the problem was and what the solution was. You can accept your own answer after 2 days.

Comment: Actually I didn't analyze pretty much why the server started to work, It happened straight after I've run your NAT commands.